# почему не создает бд в пайтоне? SQLITE3

Tags: python, sqlite3

В общем не могу понять почему не создается бд и в нее не записываются данные. Использую библиотеку pyTelegramAPI . Буду рад совету.

```
def get_connection():
    print(1)
    __connection
    if __connection is None:
        __connection = sqlite3.connect('Notebook_log.db')
        conn.commit()

def init_db(force: bool=False): #Если сменить на True то пересоздастся
    conn = get_connection()
    c = conn.cursor()
    if force:
        c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book_notebook')
        c.execute("\n"
                  "        CREATE TABLE book_notebook (\n"
                  "            id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                  "            user_id             INTEGER NOT NULL,\n"
                  "            text                TEXT NOT NULL\n"
                  "            )\n"
                  "\n"
                  "")

    conn.commit()
def add_message(user_id: int, text: str):
    conn = get_connection()
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO book_notebook (user_id, text ) VALUES (?,?)", (user_id, text))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Этот код даже запускаться не должен.

Comment: по какой причине?

Comment: отступ в первой функции тут добавился и библиотеку sqlite3 я импортировал

Comment: @Широ, в коде есть `init_db(True)`? Кст, вы можете самостоятельно подправить вопрос (кнопка **править**), чтобы его код не вызывал подобных вопросов :)

Comment: Нет, init_db(True) нет

Comment: @Широ, база создается в `sqlite3.connect(`, поэтому если не разу не вызывался `get_connection()` то база не будет создана

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте взять этот код и адаптировать под себя.

```
import sqlite3

class DB:
   """Метод, создающий соединение с базой данных, либо новую базу данных(при её отсутствии по пути path_name)"""
   def __init__(self, path_name):
       self.path_name = path_name
       self.connection = sqlite3.connect(path_name)
       self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
       print('Конструктор таблицы запущен')

x = DB(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\tpy\mydatabase.db")
x.close()
```

Comment: а почему мой код не работает?